# How to use ESP-01 GPIOs for input?

Tags: esp8266, pins

I'm trying to use one of ESP-01 GPIOs as an input, however, I'm always reading 1 and nothing attached to these pins.

Basically, I'm trying to detect high voltage from another sensor like a touch sensor or infrared to do some stuff (initial state will be low, so boot won't be affected).

**So what I'm supposed to do to read the actual value 0?**

Here is the code I'm running:

```
#define PIN0 0
#define PIN2 2
#define PIN3 3 // Using RX as GPIO

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200,SERIAL_8N1,SERIAL_TX_ONLY);
  pinMode(PIN0, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN3, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(PIN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(PIN3, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("PIN0: ");  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIN0));  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("PIN2: ");  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIN2));  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("PINRX: ");  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIN3));  Serial.println("");

  delay(500);
}
```

Here is the Serial Reading:

```
PIN0: 1 PIN2: 1 PINRX: 1
PIN0: 1 PIN2: 1 PINRX: 1
PIN0: 1 PIN2: 1 PINRX: 1
PIN0: 1 PIN2: 1 PINRX: 1
```

Comment: esp-01**S** has pull-up on io 0

Answer (score 2):

You are writing `0` to an input pin. From the [Arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/):

"If the pin is configured as an INPUT, digitalWrite() will enable (HIGH) or disable (LOW) the internal pullup on the input pin. It is recommended to set the `pinMode()` to INPUT_PULLUP to enable the internal pull-up resistor."

Also, when you leave an input pin floating, ie. don't connect anything to it, and also don't enable (or explicitly disable) the internal pull-up or connect an external pull-up, the input pin can show `1`, or it could show `0`.

TL;DR: You shouldn't leave the input pins floating; floating pins are susceptible to electrical noise and can show anything or even fluctuate. If you want them to show `0` when nothing is connected, add an external pull-down resistor.